# How to skip or ignore find tables MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've a macro code (created by Davy C) to find paragraph styles and add comment for each one if found. I need to improve this code. I want to run this macro code only paragraphs and need to skip/ignore tables when found. How do I do this?

```
Sub CheckKeepWithNext01()
    Const message As String = "Check Keep With Next"
    Const styleMask As String = "Bold + KWN"
    Dim paragraphCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentStyle As String
    Dim doc As Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    paragraphCount = doc.Paragraphs.count

    Do While i < paragraphCount
        i = i + 1

        If doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Bold = True Then
            If doc.Paragraphs(i).KeepWithNext = False Then
                currentStyle = doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Style

                If Left(currentStyle, Len(styleMask)) <> styleMask Then
                    doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Select
                    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
                    Selection.TypeText Text:=message
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

See below screenshot for more clarity:

[image: Screenshot 01]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer!

```
If doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Tables.count = 0 Then
```